# Custom ValidationAttribute returns Exception instead of ValidationMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Custom Validator that checks if a field value exists in a database table (if so then the validation is true), debugging the code actually does the validation BUT when it's false it throws the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.'
```

Checking the details the error occurs when the validation returns false on the IsValid condition (false)

The Validation class looks like this:

```
public class dotValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            string valRut = value.ToString();
            valRut = valRut.ToUpper();
            valRut = valRut.Replace(".", "");
            valRut = valRut.PadLeft(valRut.Length + 10, '0');

            using (entity1 db = new entity1())
            {
                var validation = db.viewDot.Where(x => x.RUT_DV == valRut).FirstOrDefault();

                if (validation == null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                }
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

Model validation:

```
[dotValidator(ErrorMessage="Value doesnt exists! Check the field again.")]
public string rutColaborador { get; set; }
```

And the exception shows on the POST `db.SaveChanges()` line:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddReg(licenciasUsuario lic, string FileUpload)
        {

            using (entity1 db = new entity1())
            {


                if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
                    //DO STUFF TO STORE INTO DE DB HERE
                    //Exception here!
                    db.SaveChanges();


                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Row added." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return ViewBag.Message;
                }
            }

        }
```

Can I "skip" the exception and show the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your Code throw `DbEntityValidationException` exception.

`DbEntityValidationException` is the exception thrown by Entity Framework when entity validation fails. While this exception is extremely valuable, the exception message omits the most important bit of information.

The easiest solution is to override `SaveChanges` in your `DbContext`. You can catch the `DbEntityValidationException`, unwrap the actual errors and create a new `DbEntityValidationException` with the improved message.

Example:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
{
      //....................................
      //....................................
      /*........ your DbSet other..........*/
      //....................................
      //....................................

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
        var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

        // Join the list to a single string.
        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

        // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
         var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

        // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can find the original exception. Hopefully it's help you.

Comment: Thanks, I did the override and the validation works but ValidationResult (when null) it's ignored and the row gets stored either way...